# Block scoping with nested var shows different errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, codeblocks, declaration

I'm trying to understand block scoping on ES6 and found the following issue (maybe I'm just misunderstanding the concept):

In the first test I tried the following and got the commented error:

```
{
    const x = 2;
    console.log( x );   //2
    {
        let x = "b";
        console.log(x); //b
        {
            var x = true; //Identifier 'x' has already been declared
        }
    }

}
console.log(x)
```

But when I try to get the type of the "already declared" x I get :

```
{
    const x = 2;
    console.log( x );   //2
    {
        let x = "b";
        console.log(x);  //b
        {
            console.log(typeof x); //this throws Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
        }
    }

}
console.log(x);
```

I'll keep trying to see what is going on, any ideas are accepted.

Comment: I tried the typeof without declaring in that block to see wich one of the above it was taking, or any hint to find out what happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to know the difference between **let** and **var**

> **let** allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the **var** keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. An explanation of why the name "let" was chosen can be found here. 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Second, you got this error `"Identifier 'x' has already been declared"` because you already have **"let x"** so you can't use **"var x"**. However, if you change the var to let, it will work.

**Example to understand scoping:**

```
function test() {     // first scope
   let x = 1;
   let y = 2;
   console.log(x, y); //1 2

   function test2() {  // second scope
     let x = 2;
     let z = 3;
     console.log(x,y,z); //2 2 3

   }
   test2();
   console.log(z); //z is not defined... notice z is defined in the second scope, not the first one
}
test();
```

Keep in mind, you can access variables from higher/global scopes in inner scopes, but you can't access variables from inner scopes in higher/global scopes.

Read this: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

**EDIT:**

If you do this, it should work fine

```
const x = 2;
console.log( x );   //2
{
    let x = "b";
    console.log(x); //b
    {
         x = true;
    }
}
console.log(x)
```

OR

```
const x = 2;
console.log( x );   //2
{
    let x = "b";
    console.log(x); //b
    {
        let x = true;
    }
}
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @moe-kanan. I have read and understand the concepts and differences, but in this case I would like to know the exact cause and reason for the error. I tought the js hoisting would make the inner x (var) global, but not sure why is showing this specific behavior.

Comment: Yes I have tested some other scenarios (loops, if) and looked that the **var** under the **let** will show the same error, but with functions it worked fine. I guess is part of the spec but couldn't find a direct answer on the docs, I think this solve it.

Comment: @CRz Yes, I guess "let" respects the curly brackets, but var don't :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your error comes from the final `console.log(x);`.  Removing that line makes your code work fine.

This error makes perfect sense.  `x` is only defined in inner blocks; it doesn't exist in the outer scope.

Comment: In that case it would throw a Reference Error, try removing it and it would still have the same result. I know the error is for usinr "var" but don't now the exact answer.